# error: cs0131 The left-hand side of an assingnment must be a variable, property or indexer

Tags: c#

I've tried to make a text adventure and a got an error when I get to the "if" part. I got it to work once but not like I wanted it.

I changed it a bit and then gave up and went to the original script but it wasn't working like last time and instead gave me this error:

> cs0131 The left-hand side of an assingnment must be a variable,
>   property or indexer

Here is my code:

```
Console.WriteLine("What's your name");
string name = Console.ReadLine();
Console.Write("Hello " + name);
Console.WriteLine(" do you like games?");
Console.WriteLine("yes or no");
string yes = Console.ReadLine();
string no = Console.ReadLine();

if (Console.ReadKey() = yes) { Console.WriteLine("Great!, Lets play one"); }
//the error is at "if (console.readkey()"
```

Comment: You're using the assignment operator (=) instead of equals (==). It should be `Console.ReadKey() == yes`.

Comment: Plus: `Console.ReadKey()` will not return what you expect, please read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85(v=vs.110).aspx). You probably meant `string answer = Console.ReadLine(); if (answer == "yes")...`

Answer (score 3):

In C# and many languages, there is a distinction between assigning a variable is equal to a value and testing for equality.

In C# `=` is used to assign values. `int x = 1;` will create a variable with the value `1`.

`==` is used to test a value, so you would write `if (x == 100) { /* something */ }`

Answer (score 1):

Going on your current code, you probably should have something more like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("yes or no");
string answer = Console.ReadLine();

if (answer == "yes") { Console.WriteLine("Great!, Lets play one"); }
```

Major differences are:

1. You are reading the answer a user types after asking yes or no, however in your code you are then trying to re-read another answer. Which doesn't quite make sense. The console will hang until the user enters another response.
2. [As JamesFaix said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51771700/833070), you are then trying to assign a value to `Console.ReadKey()` of whatever the user responded with first, after you asked them if they want to play. Instead you should be checking if the user's response was a positive reply.

Comment: 1st thank you 2nd can you explain that #if is used for?

Comment: The if is checking if the user entered prompt is equal to the string "yes". If so, it displays your message